# Python Web Scraping - Selector issue

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

when I try to scrappy a web site I describe the path using CSS selector but it give me a None and i don't know were is the problem.

I try also to get the information using xpath but i get the same result I try to accede to tha peth using class data-purpose and data-testid but the same error.

Comment: Maybe you need to alter *something* about the code you neglected to post?

Comment: I’m afraid there is no way we can help without seeing relevant code.

Comment: <span data-testid="seo-rating">Rating: 4.7 out of 5</span>
when i whent to accede to ratingIn [13]: rating = response.xpath('//span[@data-testid="seo-rating"]/text()').get()^M
    ...: print(rating)
None